# What's with the bat branding and its consequences?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Why do the prisoners attack the guy with the bat brand in *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice*?  I'd think many of them are in there *because* of Batman.  Why would a person branded by Batman be especially in danger?

Answer (score 17):

Apparently this is somewhat [explained in the *Ultimate Edition*](http://www.cutprintfilm.com/features/batman-v-superman-ultimate-edition-differences/):

> The theatrical cut made a big deal about Batman branding criminals
>   with a red-hot bat-symbol branding iron, and briefly mentioned that
>   inmates in prisons with this brand are quick to be killed by fellow
>   prisoners… for some reason? It was all kind of vague. **In the *Ultimate
>   Edition* we see that Lex and company pay one of the inmates to “shiv”
>   the latest bat-brandee in the prison yard. This is all part of Lex’s
>   plan to stoke the fires of Superman’s outrage at Batman’s methods.**

[CinemaBlend expands on this](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1528859/8-major-changes-batman-v-superman-made-for-the-ultimate-edition?story_page=4):

> Remember Cesar Santos? The criminal near the beginning of the movie
>   who Batman branded? Well, there was a lot more to his story in the
>   Ultimate Edition.
>
> We already knew that the Bat-Brand was a death
>   sentence if you're caught with one in prison, but that also makes it a
>   suitable cover for pulling off a sinister assassination. Anatoli is
>   seen paying off one of Cesar's fellow inmates, and later, that same
>   man stabs Cesar to death during recreation time.
>
> Like in the
>   theatrical movie, **Clark is sent pictures of Cesar (by Lex Luthor), but
>   this time, one of the photos is of his corpse.** Clark then goes to
>   Gotham City to learn about Cesar's death, and while the police aren't
>   being cooperative, **he comes across Cesar's girlfriend and son. She
>   tells him that the police know the brand means eventual murder, but
>   they won't do anything about it.** Clark wants to help by telling her
>   story via The Daily Planet, but **she retorts that a pen won't stop
>   Batman, only a fist.**
>
> This helps clear up why Superman was willing to
>   switch from words to force during their later battle.

Comment: Wow, they *really* cut some stuff out of that film. This might even have calmed down some of those "evil Batman" whiners.

Comment: There's a useful answer. I never thought to look it up, since I thought it was just nonsense like the rest of that film.

Comment: Maybe time for you to copy your answer [here too](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165692/why-would-the-bat-brand-attract-violence-from-other-criminals)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Good call! Hadn't seen that one.